# Can I launch the GRUB loader after I have loaded Ununtu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bash

Is there anyway to quickly launch the GRUB from the bash or otherwise? For instance if I wanted to quickly switch over to Windows or something without restarting my computer? I am only a week in to linux and I appologize if this seems like  stupid question. I am still learning. I did google this before posting. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes time to help out.

Comment: `grub` is a boot loader so is only executed during boot. The term 'dual boot' means you can boot more than one operating system yes, but only one will run at a time (the bootloader picks which will run).  To run another OS inside the other, usually a VM or virtual-machine is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grub` is a boot loader so is only executed during boot.

The term 'dual boot' means you can boot more than one operating system yes, but only one will run at a time (the bootloader is used to select which will run).

To run another OS inside a different OS, usually a VM or virtual-machine is used.

Comment: I understand that, but I guess I just am asking can I launch the GRUB without shutting down to make that switch? Similar to how you can hold shift and restart in Windows to launch your other OS or by launching EasyBCD? Or do I have to restart first? Thank you!

Comment: Grub is started by your machine's BIOS/firmware so it's not called or operated by the OS.  If you make a running OS call it; the OS that calls it will be in effect dead (it won't be returned control back, so you'll have achieved an unclean reboot.  There are `grub` testers that will allow you to run `grub` in a simulated environment, but they're for viewing changes made to grub & on selecting an OS you end the test.  `grub` is a boot loader, so is intended for the BIOS initiated boot process.  You can adjust `grub.cfg` from within `bash` so it alters what it does, but the code runs on reboot

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing it up! I would say I am nowhere near ready to edit my grub.cfg lol. And may never be.. but I hope so. I love computers but now-a-days there is so much going on it is hard to know where to start learning. But the separation of BIOS vs OS control certainly clarifies things for me. Thanks for taking the time @guiverc. And, btw, I am new to stack exchange as well... if there is any other way for me to up vote your answer or give you rep, please enlighten me!

Comment: FYI:  Key is probably in it's name "grand unified **Bootloader**"; it's job is to 'boot' or kick the machine into operation...  The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is text so easy to view, change & probably also muck up... and have your system fail to boot (yikes!) but as you long as you document what you did (or have a copy in the directory; eg. grub.cfg.old) you boot a 'live' system, navigate to the directory & correct it, ie. 60 secs later it's back where it was... We learn by our stuff ups (just document what you do so you can reverse it!)